# Load Div after Submit Required Fields on PHP Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a hidden div I am loading on click of submit button. I also have .notShouldBeBlank on the script for the form. What is the right method so that the php sends results and the hidden div will not load until all required fields are complete? It's currently loading the hidden div and sending results as soon as I click submit. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$name = stripslashes($name);
$address = stripslashes($address);
$city = stripslashes($city);
$state = stripslashes($state);
$phone = stripslashes($phone);
$email = stripslashes($email);


$to  = 'myemail@thisismywebsite.com ' . ', ';
$to .= $Email; 

$from = "$Email ";
$subject = 'Look and Learn: Applicant'; 
$message = <<<EOF
<html>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<b>Look and Learn: Applicant</b><br /><br />

<b>Name:</b> $name<br />
<b>Address:</b> $address / $city, $state<br />
<b>Phone:</b> $phone<br />
<b>Email:</b> $email<br />

</body>
</html>
EOF;
//end of message

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Razor Chic of Atlanta <info@thebrlab.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$to = "$to";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Sign Up</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sign-up.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click(function() {
$('#thankyou').show();
$("#hidden1").html($("#thankyou").html());
});
});

</script>

<script>
$('#myContact').submit(function () {

$.each($('#myContact .notShouldBeBlank'), function()
{
if($(this).val() == ''){
$(this).after('<span class="error">This field is required.</span>');
}
});

// Other groups validated here
}
</script>

</head>
<body style="overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">



<div id="wrap">
<div id="hidden1"></div>
<div style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
Sign-Up: Look And Learn Class
</div>

<br>

<form id="form" action="" name="myContact" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
<label>
<span>Name: *</span><br>
<input name="name" type="text" size="64" placeholder="Name">
</label>
</div>

<div>
<table width="100%" >

<tr>

<td width="230">
<label>
<span>Address: *</span><br>
<input placeholder="Address" size="100" type="text" name="address" maxlength="100">
</label>
</td>

<td width="160">
<label>
<span>City *</span><br>
<input placeholder="City" name="city" type="text" id="city" maxlength="100" />
</label>
</td>

<td width="189">
<label>
<span>State *</span><br>
<input placeholder="State" name="city" type="text" id="city" maxlength="3" />
</label>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

<div>
<label>
<span>Phone: *</span><br>
<input placeholder="Phone" size="64" type="text" name="phone">
</label>
</div>


<div>
<label>
<span>Email: *</span><br>
<input placeholder="Email address" size="64" type="email" name="email">
</label>
</div>

<div>
<button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">S  I  G  N    U  P</button>
</div>
</form>
<p>Note: * Fields are required</p>

</div>


<!---- THANK YOU---->
<?php
if($sent){

echo '<div id="thankyou" style="display:block;">';
}
else{
echo '<div id="thankyou" style="display:none;">';
}
?>


<!---- PAY BEGINS ---->
<div id="paynow1-wrapper">
<div id="paynow1">

<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="Razorchicofatlanta@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Look and Learn: Deposit">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/thank-you.html">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">

<input style="background: none" onMouseOver="this.src='images/pay-now-up.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/pay-now-down.png'" type="image" src="images/pay-now-down.png" height="41" width="141" border="0" alt="Pay Now" class="button">

</form>

</div>
</div> 
<!---- PAY ENDS ---->


<!---- PAY BEGINS ---->
<div id="paynow2-wrapper">
<div id="paynow2">

<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="Razorchicofatlanta@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Look and Learn: Balance">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="99.00">            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/thank-you.html">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">

<input style="background: none" onMouseOver="this.src='images/pay-now-up.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/pay-now-down.png'" type="image" src="images/pay-now-down.png" height="41" width="141" border="0" alt="Pay Now" class="button">

</form>

</div>
</div> 
<!---- PAY ENDS ---->



<!---- PAY BEGINS ---->
<div id="paynow3-wrapper">
<div id="paynow3">

<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="Razorchicofatlanta@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Look and Learn: Full Payment">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="199.00">            
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/thank-you.html">
<input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">

<input style="background: none" onMouseOver="this.src='images/pay-now-up.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/pay-now-down.png'" type="image" src="images/pay-now-down.png" height="41" width="141" border="0" alt="Pay Now" class="button">

</form>

</div>
</div> 
<!---- PAY ENDS ---->



<img src="images/thank-you/look-and-learn1.png" />

</div>
<!---- THANK YOU---->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form ID is "form", not "myContact". Change form id to myContact.

Then you have 2 "onsubmit" events, one in jQuery and the other inline (onSubmit). Try to merge them into one to avoid unexpected behaviors.

Also, make sure you return false on your submit event function if the validation fails, so the submit is halted.

**Update 1**

JavaScript:

```
$('#myContact').submit(function () {

    $.each($('#myContact .notShouldBeBlank'), function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).after('<span class="error">This field is required.</span>');
            return false;
        }
    });
    /* Uncomment the line below if you really have a validateForm() function */
    // return validateForm()
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myContact" action="" name="myContact" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks Edgar. How do I merge the two onsubmits?

Comment: You can just put `return validateForm()` at the final of your `$('#myContact').submit(function () {` function, just where you have the comment `// Other groups validated here`

Comment: Ok, I attempted to change my form ID to "myContact". I also inserted the return validateForm() But I'm getting back an error. Do I close validateForm() with a semi-colon? Here's the error I'm getting http://thebrlab.com/razor-chic-of-atlanta/sign-up.php

Comment: Sorry when I click on your link I see this message: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/87/5237487/html/razor-chic-of-atlanta/sign-up.php on line 248`

Comment: Were you able to pull up the link?

Comment: Yes, now I was able. I see the same code as the code you posted. Could you apply the changes I told? BTW validateForm doesn't seems to exist.

Comment: Yes it's the same code as I posted, only because when I applied return validateForm() and changed the form ID, I got back those errors. Can you please tell me how it can work without returning error?

Comment: See Update 1 with the corrected code. Could you try it?

Comment: OK, I tried it. That only shoots out blank results to my email when loading the page.

Comment: Hey Edgar, I'm having trouble here. Sorry about that I appreciate your help. I created validateForm() function. Uncommented return validateForm(). I'm still getting blank results to my email when loading the page.

Comment: Hi @juanberas sorry for the delay. I understand that the question is answered and now you are facing another problem related with your PHP script. As this is another question I suggest you to post another question for this issue. I don't mean to be rude, I would be glad to help, but these are the guidelines of StackOverflow.